# What's the difference between logging and logger export log?

Tags: python, logging

In Python, the logging module have two way to export the log:

```
import logging

logging.warning("hello")

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)  # second way os logger.
logger.warning("hello")
```

What's the difference between them?

Comment: The latter lets you see *where* in the app the log came from. Did you read e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-from-multiple-modules, following on to https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

In a application you can have multiple loggers. For example one for your emails or another one for your database etc. `logging.warning("hello")` will always log into the root logger. You usually use it if you want to debug or just log everything. `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` will create a named logger. if you put for example `logging.getLogger('app.db')` this logger will only log for that package. the `__name__` variable will use the name of the current file with the package. so you don't have to put a string.